# Why is only a few results are shown in allure report

Tags: allure

When generating a report in Allure of the test cases I have run, I am only finding a few of them are being picked up and displayed in the report.

For example out of 20 tests spread across 4 feature files (Specflow) have been executed

Yet only 1 feature and 5 tests are displayed in the report, all tests passed with no issues and are set in a similar .

They were executed in parallel on a selenium grid and i can see the JSON in the allure-reports folder has been created but when it comes to creating the report it only seems to display 1 feature.

Here is an image of all the JSON for the tests

[image: JSON Directory]

Does anyone know why this might be?

Command used to generate the report

```
allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report
```

Comment: I know the JSON image is pretty useless, it's just to prove there is output in that directory and more than 5 tests worth.

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out, this is due to having scenarios named the same in different feature files.

Although this does not cause an issue in Specflow it seems there are some complications with the allure reporting tool.

After adding a unique number to the end of each scenario involved, all showed up in the report.

Comment: Do you have any examples of your implementation? I'm having the same issue using allure-pytest

Comment: Hi @RafaelC. I do not unfortunately as we decided to rip this out of our framework. But the solution was to look for Scenario titles (Test name) that are the same but spread across different feature files. A tip would be to make sure every test has a unique name.